# can I specify the ipython store magic path

Tags: ipython

Is it possible to specify which directory the %store magic stores variables in? All my ipython config files are in ~/.config. However, my home directory is size limited by my employers and I'd like to dump ipython variables to my local storage folder.

Also, is it possible to dump everthing from this session using %store?

Thanks

Niall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the location of your whole IPython config directory with the `IPYTHONDIR` environment variable. I don't think there's currently any way of setting the %store database location separately.

No, %store doesn't have a mode to dump all the variables in your session. If you want to do that, you could take a look at dill: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have come across the IPYTHONDIR before, however, I was hoping to have all my config files etc in my home directory (which is regularly backed up) and keep my transient data in my data dump directory between sessions. Dill looks really interesting though. I'll give it a go and let you know if   the problem

Comment: Still not got it to work but your suggestion is looking like the answer. FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18381348/dill-dump-session-with-ipython